# How to delete existing record that is already loaded using hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am loading data as per daily routine in a external table of hive from local file system and it is around one year of data I have in my table. Today client informed me that the yesterday`s data was incorrect. Now how to delete the yesterday's data from the table which has already a huge amount of data in it.

Comment: **(1)** "delete existing record" is not the same as "delete the yesterday's data" (Unless you load 1 record per day...)  **(2)** You haven't supply any information on the table/directories

Answer (score -1):

You can only delete data from hive table by using **Hive Transaction Management**.But there are certain limitations:

1)File format should be orc type.
2)Your table must be bucketed.
3)Transaction can not be enabled on external table because its out of meta store control.

By default transaction management feature is off. You can turn this on by updating hive-site.xml file.